# Secure Connection Failed. The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified

Tags: asp.net

Why this post is different.
If I use a VPN it works. Which gives me different Network.

Secure Connection Failed. The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.

Details:
The Web Server is Win 10 Pro Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.471)
Computer used to access web page is Win 10 Pro Version 1803 (OS Build 17134.472)

My computer and the web page computer is on the same local network.

For Internet access I use a Mediacom Modem with port forwarding (80 & 443) to my router (Netgear 3700).

I have a DNS entry from a different ISP that forwards requests to the Mediacom Modem.

The Problem:
From my computer I get the above error if I try and go to the website using my DNS entry, Example: 
This used to work good, but now it doesn't; I suspect it has something to do with MS updates.

If I get out of my local network and access the page it works great with HTTPS.
I do this from my cell phone with My WiFi connection turned off. This forces the phone to use my carrier for the connection which is, of course, a totally different network.

I Have a Rewrite Rule in my Web.config as follows:

```
<rule name="HTTP Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true"
      patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(.*)" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
     <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

This Rewrite Rule has worked well in the past to redirect to HTTPS.

Does anyone have a suggestion on how to fix this ?
I have search many sites with ideas but none work.

Thanks
-Bob-